# calendarList().list not showing all calenders

Tags: python, api, calendar

I would like to list all my calenders in Google Calender. At the moment I have 12 calenders but only 9 are listed and I can't get the other 3 in the list. My python code is the one from the google pages.

```
page_token = None
while True:
   calendar_list = calendarService.calendarList().list(pageToken=page_token).execute()
   for calendar_list_entry in calendar_list['items']:
      print (calendar_list_entry['summary'])
   page_token = calendar_list.get('nextPageToken')
   if not page_token:
      break
```

Comment: Please share the current and expected output.

Comment: Expected is a list of dictionaries for 12 calenders. Current is a list with 9 Calenders. There is no reason for the 3 missing to not be listed. I can't share the output as in contains personal data.